# Whitespace in .gitattributes patterns

Tags: git, gitattributes

I am writing some tools for git that make use of [smudge/clean filters](http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-2.html), and so I must create entries in the `.gitattributes` file.

Unfortunately, that file is parsed rather simply by splitting on whitespace, and so it is does not seem possible to me to include an explicit space character in the pattern.

I have been replacing whitespace characters with `?`, which matches again zero or one characters.

Ergo, a pattern of `has?spaces` will match against my target filename of `has spaces`, but also `hasspaces`.

Is there a way to only match spaces, or am I stuck with the near-match?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try, as part of your pattern:

```
[[:space:]]
# as in
has[[:space:]]spaces
```

The [gitattributes man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) does mention an [example with it](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8d8387116ae8c3e73f6184471f0c46edbd2c7601/Documentation/gitattributes.txt#L563-L564).
And the [pattern tests also include several examples](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8d8387116ae8c3e73f6184471f0c46edbd2c7601/t/t3070-wildmatch.sh#L144):

```
match 1 x ' ' '[[:digit:][:upper:][:space:]]'
```

Comment: This does match against less things, but it could still grab (terribly named) files with tabs and newlines in them. Perhaps that is enough...

Comment: @MikeBoers it should answer precisely the question you originally asked, though .

Comment: +1, using `[[:space:]]` or `[[:blank:]]` is currently probably the best workaround available. Perhaps we will eventually see [a _true_ fix for the issue](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/242176) in one of the next Git versions.