# How do I define a .gitattributes rule for a file with spaces in it?

Tags: git, merge, gitattributes

I've read the [documentation on .gitattributes](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) and [searched Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18864698/whitespace-in-gitattributes-patterns) for a simple answer to this question, but so far haven't found it. I have a file with spaces in it like so.

```
Reserved\ Slots.txt merge=mergeslots
```

I have also tried to use quotes instead of escaping the space.

```
"Reserved Slots.txt" merge=mergeslots
```

How do I use a custom merge driver for a file with spaces in it?

Comment: It should work as presented: ["Patterns that begin with a double quote are quoted in C style."](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes)

Comment: Is that the exact filename? With a *real space* (code=32)? Sometimes Windows uses 'not real spaces'..

Comment: @user2864740 `mergeslots` is a Python file that should output it the console what it's doing, but I still get `CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in Reserved Slots.txt` which should not be occurring.

Comment: The file was also created on an Ubuntu instance automatically by a program and then being merged in a Docker instance.

Comment: I just checked the output of another Docker instance and now I'm seeing `Slots.txt" is not a valid attribute name: .gitattributes:3`.

Comment: Struggling with this too. It seems a mess. On linux, escaping the space with backslash seems to be required. On windows, you have to quote the string that contains a space. Doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Whitespace in .gitattributes patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18864698/whitespace-in-gitattributes-patterns) use

```
[[:space:]]
# as in
has[[:space:]]spaces
```